# Dar replace de um texto por uma imagem

Tags: java, android

Gostava de saber se seria possível dar *replace* de um pedaço de texto por uma imagem que é feita através de URL?

Quero substituir imagem 1 , imagem 2 e imagem 3 por imagens que estão num array JSON , o que está no array JSON é somente o URL das imagens.

Um print da minha apk:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Conseguiu?@TiagoCoelho

Answer (score 1):

Sim podes fazer isso assim:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.site.pt/url_da_imagem");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```